# What technique is applied to a traffic light system to make sure it is still safe even when errors occur?

Tags: controller

From time to time traffic lights stop operating properly - and so instead of directing the traffic they start flashing yellow and someone from the traffic maintenance must show up to fix them. Does anyone know what  technique is applied to a traffic light system to make sure it is still safe for us even when errors occur?

Comment: If they fail, they should flash red (in the US), not yellow. Flashing yellow indicates proceed with caution (no stop required). Flashing red (or no light at all) should be treated like a stop sign.

Comment: Not a good question for this site, but... I've seen some lights that go to yellow during periods and only RYG for other periods of the day.

Comment: @ThePhoton, not always.  In some intersections you will see one side as yellow and one side as red.  But you will likely never see both sides go yellow as that would be a tad dangerous.

Comment: @ThePhoton - e.g. in germany they will always flash yellow. When they flash, traffic signs have precedence.

Comment: @ThePhoton, Where I live, disabled traffic lights either flash yellow or are completely dark (if power went out etc). Flashing yellow means that the light does not work and you should drive according to the signs (stop/main road/secondary road). If there are no such signs, then the intersection is equal and the car on your right has priority.

Comment: @KrisBahnsen, I've seen the mode you describe very rarely, but used as a normal operating mode, for example very late at night. I've always seen flashing red all ways in the event of a failure. But this probably varies not just country-to-country but state-to-state within the US.

Comment: Potentially this could be on-topic if it was more focused on how to design fail-safes in electronics and why you would need to fail to a flashing state instead of restating. But on the surface it looks like this doesn't have anything to do with design.

Comment: @PetPaulsen, Pentium100, where I live people would get very confused if there was both a stop sign and a traffic light at the same intersection. But we're not known for being the most carefully-trained drivers in the world.

Comment: It is a good question. I am interested to know how the engineers setup a safe system on the traffic light. Please open the silo.